# Why we can't use Integration by substitution for $\int_{-1}^1 x^2\mathrm{d}x$ with $x^2=u$

Tags: integration

It is said at the last discussion ([The link toward the discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380669/proof-all-integrals-are-zero#2380675)) about integration by substitution $f$ must be bijective over $[a,b]$, with this example to illustrate :

$\int_{-1}^1 x^2\mathrm{d}x$ with $u =x^2$

I have found one example which $f$ is not bijective over $[a,b]$ and the u-substitution is suitable.

$\displaystyle I=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos(x)\cos(\sin(x))dx$

So if $\varphi(x) =\sin(x)\implies \displaystyle  I=\int_{\varphi(-\pi/2)}^{\varphi(-\pi/2)} \varphi'(x)\cos\left(\varphi(x)\right)dx\iff\int_{-1}^1\cos(u)du=2\sin(1)$

And my question is :

The condition on the function $cos$ is : $\cos\in \mathcal{C}^1([\varphi(a),\varphi(b)],\mathbb{R})$ Am I right ?

---

And  for $\int_{-1}^1 x^2\mathrm{d}x$ with $u =x^2$

$\implies \displaystyle \int_{1}^1 \dfrac{\sqrt{u}}{2} du$ and I don't think $f$ can be continuous over one point!?

Am I right?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you're asking for the first part. $x\to\sin(x)$ *is* a  bijective mapping on the interval in question

Comment: $f:x\to \cos x \cos (\sin x)$ is not bijective

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801307/does-the-change-of-variable-function-have-to-be-injective

Comment: @ThomasGrubb, Yes it's right, I found a bad example. I will find an another example. But for $\int_{-1}^1 x^2\mathrm{d}x$ does it make sense my reasoning?

Comment: @stu $x\mapsto \cos x\cos (\sin x)$ is not the function used for the subsitution.  $x\mapsto \sin x $ is, and it is bijective over $[-\pi/2;\pi/2)$

Comment: If $u=x^2$, then $du=2xdx$. **But** $x=\sqrt{u}$ when $x>0$ and $x=-\sqrt{u}$ when $x<0$. So $$\int_{-1}^1x^2\,dx=\int_{-1}^0x^2dx+\int_0^1x^2dx=0.5\int_1^0(-\sqrt{u})\,du+0.5\int_0^1\sqrt{u}\,du$$ But the first term gets flipped to $0.5\int_0^1\sqrt{u}\,du$, so the sum is $\int_0^1\sqrt{u}\,du$, which is indeed equal to $\int_{-1}^1x^2\,dx$.

Comment: The point is that you carried out the substitution incorrectly. **It is not true that $x=\sqrt{u}$ for all $x$ in $(-1,1)$.**

Comment: @symplectomorphic Thanks, I was looking for an argument because $\varphi$ can be bijective. Good night!!