# Is this version of change of variable theorem in Apostol correct?

Tags: real-analysis

In `Mathematical Analysis', Second Edition, T. M. Apostol, we have the following theorem for change of variable in Riemann Integral.(Page 164, Theorem 7.36)

> Assume that $g$ has a continuous derivative $g'$ on an interval [c,d].  Let $f$ be continuous on $g([c,d])$ and define $F$ by the equation $$F(x)=\int_{g(c)}^x f(t)\,dt\text{ if }x\in g([c,d]).$$ Then, for each $x\in[c,d]$ the integral $\int_c^x f[g(t)]g'(t)dt$ exists and has the value $F(g(x))$.  In particular we have \begin{equation}\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}f(x)\,dx=\int_{c}^{d}f[g(t)]g'(t)\,dt\end{equation}

Suppose we have the integral $\int_{-4}^5\sqrt{25-x^2}\,dx$. We take $[a,b]=[-4,5]$. We take $g(t)=5\sin t$. Suppose $\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)=\alpha$, $0<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Then, it seems from the theorem that we can take $[c,d]=[\pi+\alpha,\frac{5\pi}{2}]$ or $[c,d]=[2\pi-\alpha,\frac{5\pi}{2}]$. This is clearly not right.  Apostol remarks that *Some texts require that $g'$ is never on zero on $[c,d]$, but it is not needed.* If we require $g'$ is never $0$, we will choose $[c,d]=[2\pi-\alpha,\frac{5\pi}{2}]$.

In this page [Does the change of variable function have to be injective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801307/does-the-change-of-variable-function-have-to-be-injective)
the condition $g([c,d])\subset [a,b]$ is mentioned. If this condition is imposed, we will have to choose $[c,d]=[2\pi-\alpha,\frac{5\pi}{2}]$ because $g\left([\pi+\alpha,\frac{5\pi}{2}]\right)=[-5,5]$.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why is it "clearly not right"?  You've got $\int _c ^d 25 |\cos(t)| \cos(t) \; \mathrm{d}t$ which is equal to $\int _{-4}^5 f$ for both your choices of $c$ and $d$. Maybe you had $\cos^2$ where it should be $|\cos|\cos$?

Comment: Why do you think they are not right? The theorem tells that $$\int_{\pi+\alpha}^{5\pi/2} \sqrt{25-(5\sin t)^2}(5\cos t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{2\pi-\alpha}^{5\pi/2}\sqrt{25-(5\sin t)^2}(5\cos t)\,\mathrm{d}t,$$ and indeed this can also be confirmed by directly appealing to the symmetry of sine and cosine.

Comment: Thanks Matthew Towers and Sangchul Lee. Cos is negative in $[\pi+\alpha,3\frac{\pi}{2}]$. So, the integrand will be $-\cos^2 t$ in this interval. It could be that                               $ - \int_{\pi+\alpha}^{3\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2 t\, dt$ and $\int_{3\frac{\pi}{2}}^{2\pi-\alpha}\cos^2 t\,dt$ cancel out .

Comment: In general one does not doubt a theorem by looking at/finding counter examples but one carefully studies the proof to find any flaw in the argument. Apostol's version of "change of variables" is the best I have found so far and it clears the common misconception that $g$ should be one-one mapping.

Comment: Parmanand  Singh, I didn't set out find a counter example to the theorem.  I was solving a particular problem and found the results apparently in contradiction to the theorem.  I felt that, may be, being one-one mapping is necessary.  Many well known books have mistakes. Now, things have been clarified.  Grunwald theorem in class field theory had 2 different `proofs', but Wang found a mistake because of a counter example. Such occasions are rare, but they may happen,.